# Converting Text to Image on iOS

Tags: ios, image, text, uiimageview, rendering

How to convert Text to Image and show in UIImageview.
Can anyone know the conversion from Text to Image?

Answer (score 23):

With Swift 5 and iOS 12, you can choose one the **6 following ways** in order to solve your problem.

---

### #1. Using `NSString`'s `draw(at:withAttributes:)` method

In the simplest case where you want to convert a `String` to a `UIImage` with some attributes, you can use [`draw(at:withAttributes:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1533109-draw). The following Playground codes show how to get an `UIImage` from a `String` using `draw(at:withAttributes:)`:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let text = "Hello, world"
let attributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow,
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
]
let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: attributes)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(textSize, true, 0)
text.draw(at: CGPoint.zero, withAttributes: attributes)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let text = "Hello, world"
let attributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow,
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
]
let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: attributes)

let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: textSize)
let image = renderer.image(actions: { context in
    text.draw(at: CGPoint.zero, withAttributes: attributes)
})

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

Note that `NSAttributedString` has a similar method called `draw(at:)`.

---

### #2. Using `NSString`'s `draw(in:withAttributes:)` method

As an alternative to `draw(at:withAttributes:)`, you can use [`draw(in:withAttributes:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1529855-draw).

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let text = "Hello, world"
let attributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow,
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
]
let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: attributes)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(textSize, true, 0)
let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: textSize)
text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: attributes)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let text = "Hello, world"
let attributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow,
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
]
let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: attributes)

let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: textSize)
let image = renderer.image(actions: { context in
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: textSize)
    text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: attributes)
})

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

Note that `NSAttributedString` has a similar method called `draw(in:)`.

---

### #3. Using `NSString`'s `draw(with:options:attributes:context:)` method

As an alternative to `draw(at:withAttributes:)` and `draw(in:)`, you can use [`draw(with:options:attributes:context:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1530195-draw). Note that Apple has some recommendations for `draw(with:options:attributes:context:)`:

> This method uses the baseline origin by default.
>   If `usesLineFragmentOrigin` is not specified, the rectangle’s height will be ignored and the operation considered to be single-line rendering.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let text = "Hello, world"
let attributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow,
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
]
let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: attributes)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(textSize, true, 0)
let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: textSize)
text.draw(with: rect, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin], attributes: attributes, context: nil)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let text = "Hello, world"
let attributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow,
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
]
let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: attributes)

let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: textSize)
let image = renderer.image(actions: { context in
    text.draw(with: .zero, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin], attributes: attributes, context: nil)
})

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

Note that `NSAttributedString` has a similar method called `draw(with:options:context:)`.

---

### #4. Using `CALayer`'s `render(in:)` method

If you want to capture the text of a `UILabel`, `UITextField` or `UITextView` to a `UIImage`, you can use [`render(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410909-render). The following Playground codes show how to snapshot the content text of a `UILabel` using `render(in:)`:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
label.textColor = .yellow
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
label.text = "Hello, world"
label.sizeToFit()

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(label.frame.size, true, 0)
guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { exit(0) }
label.layer.render(in: context)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
label.textColor = .yellow
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
label.text = "Hello, world"
label.sizeToFit()

let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: label.frame.size)
let image = renderer.image(actions: { context in
    label.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
})

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

---

### #5. Using `UIView`'s `drawHierarchy(in:afterScreenUpdates:)` method

If you want to capture the text of a `UILabel`, `UITextField` or `UITextView` to a `UIImage`, you can use [`drawHierarchy(in:afterScreenUpdates:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622589-drawhierarchy). Note that Apple has some recommendations for `drawHierarchy(in:afterScreenUpdates:)`:

> Use this method when you want to apply a graphical effect, such as a blur, to a view snapshot. This method is not as fast as the `snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates:)` method.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
label.textColor = .yellow
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
label.text = "Hello, world"
label.sizeToFit()

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(label.frame.size, true, 0)    
_ = label.drawHierarchy(in: label.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
label.textColor = .yellow
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
label.text = "Hello, world"
label.sizeToFit()

let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: label.frame.size)
let image = renderer.image(actions: { context in
    _ = label.drawHierarchy(in: label.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
})

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

---

### #6. Using `UIView`'s `snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates:)` method

If it's OK for you to get a `UIView` instead of a `UIImage` from your snapshot operation, you can use [`snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622531-snapshotview). The following Playground code shows how to snapshot the content text of a `UILabel` into a `UIView` using `snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates:)`:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
label.textColor = .yellow
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
label.text = "Hello, world"
label.sizeToFit()

let view = label.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Comment: Very good explanation, thanks helped a lot! Especially with playground.

Comment: Excellent summary!  One thing to note.  Should the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions opaque flag be be set to false.  I was getting a black background set to true.

Comment: @imanou Petit You have any idea how to solve this problem in iOS13 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58405106/ios13-uitextview-converting-uitextview-to-image-is-not-working-properly-working

Answer (score 12):

You can start playing around with something like this:

```
NSString *string = @"Some text";
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(80, 50));
[string drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 20)
           withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

`result` contains the UIImage with the text in it, and you can assign it to the UIImageView `image` property.

Comment: How would you make the text white?

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT 3 :

Create an extension for UIImage so that you can use it everywhere:

```
extension UIImage {
    class func imageWithLabel(label: UILabel) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(label.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        label.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img!
   }
}
```

Now where ever you need to use this to create an image from Text :

// This customisation of label is according to your needs which font , what background color you need. Feel free to change.

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 20))
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.textAlignment = .center
label.textColor = UIColor.white
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
label.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat", size: 17)
label.text = "YOUR TEXT HERE"
label.sizeToFit()
let image = UIImage.imageWithLabel(label: label)
```

Answer (score 0):

[yourImageView addSubview:textView];
    [canvas addSubview:passingImageView];

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(canvas.bounds.size);
[canvas.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return resultingImage;
```

you should take a UIView and inside take UIImageview and the above code should do the trick.Here canvas is UIView.